# Why would my entire layout be invalidated every few seconds?

Tags: android, android-layout

While trying to figure out how to highlight the selected group in an `ExpandableListView`, I noticed something strange: `getGroupView(...)` is being called on my `BaseExpandableListAdapter` every few seconds when nothing is apparently happening.  I started logging a stack trace every time it's called, and it appears that my entire layout is being invalidated.  There's often something immediately preceding it in the log, but not always, and *what* immediately precedes it varies.

```
01-07 13:49:58.423  22504-22504/com.mycompany.myapp D/JobListAdapter﹕ getGroupView 0, true, android.widget.LinearLayout@418166c8
01-07 13:49:58.426  22504-22504/com.mycompany.myapp D/JobListAdapter﹕ call stack
    java.lang.RuntimeException
            at com.mycompany.myapp.ui.map.JobListAdapter.getGroupView(JobListAdapter.java:93)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:445)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2059)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1249)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1160)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1374)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:663)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2103)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1149)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2583)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Is it normal for an activity's layout to be invalidated for no apparent reason?**  I don't think anything in the layout should be getting resized once it's been displayed, except maybe the clock which only changes once a minute.

**Edit:** Here's the list adapter.  I have since added some logging to verify that there is no activity on the event buses that could be causing the list items to refresh.

```
public class JobListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    public static final String TAG = JobListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final int INVALID_ID = 0;
    private final EventReceiver<JobStatusEvent> mJobStatusReceiver;
    private final EventReceiver<JobUpdateEvent> mJobUpdateReceiver;
    private final List<Job> mJobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
    private final JobFormatter mJobFormatter;

    private final JobListView mView;
    private final Context mContext;
    private final EventBus<JobStatusEvent> mJobStatusBus;
    private final EventBus<JobUpdateEvent> mJobUpdateBus;

    public JobListAdapter(final JobListView view, final Vehicle vehicle,
                          final EventBus<JobStatusEvent> jobStatusBus,
                          final EventBus<JobUpdateEvent> jobUpdateBus) {
        mView = view;
        mJobStatusBus = jobStatusBus;
        mJobUpdateBus = jobUpdateBus;
        mContext = view.getContext();
        mJobFormatter = new JobFormatter(mContext);

        vehicle.getAssignedAndLoadedJobs(mJobs);
        notifyDataSetChanged();


        mJobStatusReceiver = new EventReceiver<JobStatusEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(final EventBus<JobStatusEvent> bus, final JobStatusEvent event) {
                final Job job = event.getJob();
                final JobStatus status = job.getStatus();
                final int index = mJobs.indexOf(job);
                if(status == JobStatus.ASSIGNED || status == JobStatus.LOADED) {
                    if(index == -1) {
                        mJobs.add(job);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                else if(index != -1) {
                    mJobs.remove(index);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
        mJobStatusBus.register(mJobStatusReceiver);

        mJobUpdateReceiver = new EventReceiver<JobUpdateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(final EventBus<JobUpdateEvent> bus, final JobUpdateEvent event) {
                if(mJobs.contains(event.getJob())) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
        mJobUpdateBus.register(mJobUpdateReceiver);
    }

    /**
     * Causes this adapter to unregister its listeners.
     */
    public void destroy() {
        mJobStatusBus.unregister(mJobStatusReceiver);
        mJobUpdateBus.unregister(mJobUpdateReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded, View view,
                             final ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.debug(TAG, "call stack", new RuntimeException());
//      Log.debug(TAG, "getGroupView: pos=" + groupPosition + ", exp=" + isExpanded);
//      Log.debug(TAG, "getGroupId(groupPosition) = " + getGroupId(groupPosition));
//      Log.debug(TAG, "mView.getSelectedGroupId() = " + mView.getSelectedGroupId());
        final Job job = mJobs.get(groupPosition);
        if(view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.job_list_header, parent, false);
        }
        // TODO more views in job_list_header
        final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.job_number);
        if(job.hasNumber()) {
            String content = mContext.getString(R.string.job_number);
            textView.setText(content.replace("{JOB}", job.getNumber()));
        }
        else if(job.isFlagTrip()) {
            textView.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.flag_trip));
        }
        else {
            textView.setText("???");
        }
        final boolean selected = getGroupId(groupPosition) == mView.getSelectedGroupId();
        view.findViewById(R.id.selected_indicator).setVisibility(selected ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             final boolean isLastChild, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if(view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.job_list_details, parent, false);
        }
        final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.job_details);
//      textView.setText(R.string.lorem_ipsum);
        final Job job = mJobs.get(groupPosition);
        textView.setText(mJobFormatter.format(job));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mJobs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return mJobs.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1; // always one child per group
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mJobs.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // the child is simply a different display of the group
        return mJobs.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return mJobs.get(groupPosition).getListViewId();
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // note inversion
        return -mJobs.get(groupPosition).getListViewId();
    }

    @Override
    public long getCombinedGroupId(long groupId) {
        return groupId;
    }

    @Override
    public long getCombinedChildId(long groupId, long childId) {
        return childId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    public int findGroupPosition(final long groupId) {
        // group IDs are always positive
        if(groupId < 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        for(int i = 0, limit = getGroupCount(); i < limit; ++i) {
            if(getGroupId(i) == groupId) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if i can help, but can we please see the JobListAdapter code, and can you point out which is line 93 in the code?

Comment: @joshgoldeneagle Added the code.  Line 93 is `Log.debug(TAG, "call stack", new RuntimeException());`

Comment: @joshgoldeneagle It may not have anything to do with the `ListView`.  Maybe something somewhere else in the layout is changing, but I don't think so.  I'm wondering if there's some kind of configuration change that might be occurring with such frequency.  (And it's not rotation.)

Comment: Dumb question, but what do you mean exactly by "invalidated"?

Comment: @joshgoldeneagle I mean the layout appears to be running for the whole activity every few seconds, as if one of the views changed size.